# Navigate from a component which's not defined inside react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's make a example:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={HeroesList}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="login" component={Login}></Route>
      <Route path="signup" component={SignUp}></Route>
      <Route path="change/:heroId" component={ChangeHeroWrapper}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

I have an component named `ChangeHero` which is not defined inside react router, but it was call inside the `ChangeHeroWrapper` component like this:

```
class ChangeHeroWrapper extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ChangeHero hero={this.props.hero} />
        )
    }
}
```

Now I have a button called Back, so how can I navigate back from that component?
I tried `browserHistory.goBack` but it's reload the whole page, and it's need 2 times to actually go back (need to click the buttton twice, first time it reload the page, the second time it goes back).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I fixed it, turn out it's an error from the UI lib.